# min/max scale doesn't work in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2

I need to create a map service where the map scale should be between 1:5000 to 1:50000. My code is as follows:

```
var options = {
                    controls: [], 
                    scales: [5000, 50000],
                    maxScale: 1/5000,
                    minScale: 1/50000,
                    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857"),
                    displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                    maxExtent: bounds,
                    units: 'm'
                 };


         var map, vectors, controls; 
         function init(){

         map = new OpenLayers.Map('map',options);
         var gphy = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
                "Google Physical",
                {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,minZoomLevel: 6}
                );

          var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
                    "Google Streets", 
                {maxZoomLevels: 20,minZoomLevel: 6}
                );
          var ghyb = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
                    "Google Hybrid",
                    {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,maxZoomLevels: 20,minZoomLevel: 6}
                );
          var gsat = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
                    "Google Satellite",
                    {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,maxZoomLevels: 22,minZoomLevel: 6}
                );

          var vaga_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "Road",
                    "http://localhost:8090/geoserver/wms/wsNYCRoad", {
                    layers: 'vagar_alla_p',
                    styles: '', 
                    transparent:true,
                    tiled: 'false'
                },
                {
                    buffer: 0,
                    displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
                    isBaseLayer: false
                });
```

However, the zoom in/out button disappeared (upper left corner) and the map can not be zoomed at all.
[image]

If I change the code to

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map(   
            {
            div: "map",
            allOverlays: true
                 });
```

Then I do got zoom in/out button but the map can be e.g. zoomed in more than 1:5000. 
[image: as you can see, the map can be zoomed in further]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: remove the 1/ from the scales - they are denominators.

Comment: @iant I actually tried to remove 1/, still got the same result.